# While and If loop in one line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a client server app, where when i am in need to update the Client code, i am pushing an update using a string match and whenever that string matches the infinitely running client code process that.
The update is nothing but a string that contains python code in it, let's say this:

```
while True:
    if data == "exit":
        connection_status = 'Exit Request Received, Exiting'
        MessageBox(None, connection_status, "Connection Status", 0x40000 | MB_OK | ICON_STOP)               
        break
```

And in my client main code, i have something like this:

```
if 'update' in data:
    new_source = data.split('###_CODEBLOCK_###')
    exec(new_source[1])
```

From the server, i am sending something like this:

```
Enter you Message  : update code is here ###_CODEBLOCK_###while True : if data == "mad": connection_status = "Exit Request Received, Exiting" ; MessageBox(None, connection_status, "Connection Status", 0x40000 | MB_OK | ICON_STOP) ; break
```

Problem :

1. CLI doesn't like new line, therefore i have to use one-liner python code to achieve this
2. Because, it's a one-liner and while and if loop are compound statements, i can't use them the way i put in, so i need to know how can i achieve it in one-line code
3. Is this really a good hack to send updates? This is bonus question for me, if you don't answer it, that's fine

Comment: You have basically reinvented a trojan.

Comment: You can create a function with your code and call it when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function in Python and convert that multiline code into a single line string to be used as `exec()` argument. Make sure you use `\n` to indicate newline and still keep the proper spacing to indicate indentation.